# Convert folder with .npz file to one .npz

Tags: python

I have a folder containing multiple subfolders containing `.npz` files each corresponding to a song track. I want to reshape this into one single `.npz` or `.npy` file in the shape of `(n_of_songs, x, y, z)`. I can't seem to find a way. Am I viewing this wrong like, should I just iterate the whole folder then concatenate the `.npz` files(kind of a brute force), or is there a way to convert the directory itself to a `.npz`. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to stack them to one array?

Comment: @George yes I do

Answer (score 0):

With `savez_compressed` you are able to save multiple numpy arrays into a single file. See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez_compressed.html).